# How to reconstruct original signal from sampled signal?

Tags: digital-communications, sampling, nyquist, reconstruction, digital-to-analog

My original signal as

```
f1=2;
f2=5;

fs=100;
Ts=1/fs;
t=0:Ts:1;

xt=cos(2*pi*f1*t)+cos(2*pi*f2*t);

figure
plot(t,xt)
```

as shown below figure.

[image]

and my sampled signal with fs=12 which is greater than two times of
maximum frequency, 2*f2=10;

```
fs=12;
Ts=1/fs;
tn=0:Ts:1;

xn=cos(2*pi*f1*tn)+cos(2*pi*f2*tn);
```

[image]

and then I want to reconstruct the original signal with sampled signal.

I tried it using the matlab function interp1 as below

```
xr=interp1(tn,xn,t,'spline');
```

I compared original signal and reconstructed signal, but
they are different as shown below figure.

[image]

How to reconstruct original signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinc interpolation can exactly reconstruct an above-Nyquist-sampled strictly bandlimited signal from noiseless samples.  See the Whittaker-Kotelnikov-Shannon reconstruction or resampling theorem: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker–Shannon_interpolation_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula) and [https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/Theory_Ideal_Bandlimited_Interpolation.html](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/resample/Theory_Ideal_Bandlimited_Interpolation.html)

For computation, you can try using a windowed Sinc (or other near-brick-wall linear phase low pass filter) for a more reasonable finite length interpolation kernel.  For any finite length of samples, both the band-limit and the low-pass reconstruction filter's stop-band need to be strictly below (NOT equal to) half the sampling rate.  Due to finite window length, and finite-precision floating point sampling and arithmetic, you may see some end effects and other reconstruction differences.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: For ideal Sinc interpolation you need an infinite number of samples. A windowed Sinc allows you to use a finite set of samples, but you are going to have end effects and the beginning and end of your data i.e. where you run out of data.

Answer (score 1):

To implement a digital-to-analog converter, all you need is an ideal low-pass filter to filter out the periodic frequency response that $\varOmega \geq \varOmega_s/2$.

$$
H(j\varOmega) =\left\{
\begin{aligned}
T,\ \ \ \  |\varOmega|<\varOmega_s/2 \\
0,\ \ \ \  |\varOmega|\geq\varOmega_s/2
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

The impulse response of an ideal low-pass filter is a sinc function

$$
h(t) = \frac{\sin(\pi t/T)}{\pi t/T}
$$

Convolving the sampled signal with this impulse response gives the analog signal.

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_a(t) =& \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x_a(nt) h(t-nT)\\
=&\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n) \frac{\sin[\pi (t-nT)/T]}{\pi (t-nT)/T}
\end{aligned}
$$

```
f1=2;
f2=5;

fs=100;
Ts=1/fs;
t=0:Ts:1;
xt=cos(2*pi*f1*t)+cos(2*pi*f2*t);
figure
plot(t,xt)

fs=12;
Tn=1/fs;
tn=0:Tn:1;
xn=cos(2*pi*f1*tn)+cos(2*pi*f2*tn);
hold on
stem(tn, xn)

y = dac(xn, Tn, t);
plot(t,y)


function y = dac(x, T, t)
m = 0:length(x)-1;
y = zeros(1, length(t));
for ii = 1:length(t)
    h = sinc((t(ii)-m*T)/T);
    y(ii) = sum(x .* h);
end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much.